# Mass-energy equation vs chemical bonding reactions

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, physical-chemistry, binding-energy

If use $E=mc^2$ in chemical energy like needs to bonding and ...  it means there must reduced or added some mass after reaction, by [Wikipedia mass-energy equivalence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence):

> Because the speed of light is a large number in everyday units, the
>   formula implies that even an everyday object at rest with a modest
>   amount of mass has a very large amount of energy intrinsically. Chemical reactions, nuclear reactions, and other energy transformations may cause a system to lose some of its energy content to the environment (and thus some corresponding mass), releasing it as the radiant energy of light or as thermal energy.

So I would like to know what kind of [elementary particle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) are candidates for the chemical reaction mass change.

[image]

Comment: you say:releasing it as

the radiant energy of light or as thermal energy ., so the particles are photons

Comment: This may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy

Answer (score 2):

Chemical reactions can be described fully in terms of electrons, (given) nuclei and sometimes photons.